# Pass through another attribute with this helper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, helper

I am using Sinatra and an S3 bucket to serve my assets. I have the following helper that assigns the s3 bucket URL as its path but I am wondering how to pass through another attribute, such as width.

helper:

```
helpers do
  def aws_asset (path)
    File.join settings.asset_host, path
 end
end
```

config/production:

```
configure :production do
  set :asset_host, "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images"
end
```

to use this helper in my view I can then do this:

```
<%= image_tag(aws_asset "banner2.jpg") %>
```

What I want to do though is pass through a width, which I can do with the image_tag alone:

```
<%= image_tag("banner2.jpg", width: '730px') %>
```

But if I do:

```
 <%= image_tag(aws_asset "banner2.jpg", width: '730px') %>
```

I get wrong number of arguments error, 2 for 1, which I understand as I'm only passing through one attribute.

How can I change the helper to accept a width also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can clean up a bit the (sub)method invocations with some good old parentheses:

```
<%= image_tag(aws_asset("banner2.jpg"), width: '730px') %>
```

In your last snippet, Ruby assumes that you are calling the `aws_asset` method with 2 arguments: the first being `"banner2.jpg"` and the second a hash containing `width: '730px'`